# For scatterplot with matplotlib how to include in the legend gradient for dot size and colour?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend

I create two scatterplots with `matplotlib` in python with this code, the data for the code is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/118TPUVVBIG8yNCJlFCIfboe4Ue0vIclD/view?usp=sharing):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import Normalize

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3 = ax1.twinx()

norm = Normalize(vmin=0.95*min(arr), vmax=1.05*max(arr))

ax1.scatter(x, y1, s=20, c=arr, cmap='Blues_r', norm=norm, marker='x', label='bla1')
ax3.scatter(x, y2, s=(20*(1.1-arr))**3.5, c=arr, cmap='Reds_r', norm=norm, marker='^', label='bla1')
```

The created fig. looks like this:
[image]

So, the dot size (in ax3) and the dot colour (in ax1 and ax3) are taken from arrays containing floats with all kinds of values in the range [0,1]. My question: **How do I create a legend that displays the corresponding y-values for, let's say 5 different dot sizes and 5 different colour nuances?**

I would like the legend to look like in the figure below (source [here](https://blogs.oii.ox.ac.uk/bright/2014/08/12/point-size-legends-in-matplotlib-and-basemap-plots/)), but with the colour bar and size bar put into a single legend, if possible. Thanks for suggestions and code!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
# using your data in dataframe df

# create s2
df['s2'] = (20*(1.1-df.arr))**3.5

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,12))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax3 = ax1.twinx()

norm = Normalize(vmin=0.95*min(df.arr), vmax=1.05*max(df.arr))

p1 = ax1.scatter(df.x, df.y1, s=20, c=df.arr, cmap='Blues_r', norm=norm, marker='x')
fig.colorbar(p1, label='arr')
p2 = ax3.scatter(df.x, df.y2, s=df.s2, c=df.arr, cmap='Reds_r', norm=norm, marker='^')
fig.colorbar(p2, label='arr')


# create the size legend for red
for x in [15, 80, 150]:
    plt.scatter([], [], c='r', alpha=1, s=x, label=str(x), marker='^')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.23, 1), ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True, title='s2')

plt.show()
```

[image]

- There's no legend for `p1` because the size is static.
- I think this would be better as two separate plots
- I used [Customizing Plot Legends: Legend for Size of Points](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/04.06-customizing-legends.html#Legend-for-Size-of-Points)

### Separate

```py
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(20, 10))

norm = Normalize(vmin=0.95*min(df.arr), vmax=1.05*max(df.arr))

p1 = ax1.scatter(df.x, df.y1, s=20, c=df.arr, cmap='Blues_r', norm=norm, marker='x')
fig.colorbar(p1, ax=ax1, label='arr')
p2 = ax2.scatter(df.x, df.y2, s=df.s2, c=df.arr, cmap='Reds_r', norm=norm, marker='^')
fig.colorbar(p2, ax=ax2, label='arr')


# create the size legend for red
for x in [15, 80, 150]:
    plt.scatter([], [], c='r', alpha=1, s=x, label=str(x), marker='^')
plt.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(1.2, 1), ncol=1, fancybox=True, shadow=True, title='s2')

plt.show()
```

[image]